# Trait based customisation points and ODR-violation concerns in {fmt}

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, one-definition-rule, fmt

First of, I am learning C++ currently for my thesis and am therefore inexperienced with the language. Any help is appreciated.

I am using the fmt library in my code and the canonical way user provided types can be formatted is by specializing the class template type [`fmt::formatter`](http://fmtlib.net/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types).

### Example

Code in the Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/2VO_wa

Given two libraries `A` and `B`, which both happen to use fmt heavily in their implementation and both in some way or another need to print/log the current time.
Both might reasonably use `std::chrono::system_clock` and, wanting to format this at several points, each define their own version of `fmt::formatter<std::chrono::system_clock::time_point>` in order to make this simple code possible:

```
auto msg = fmt::format("It is now {}", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

Library `A` uses a different implementation than `B`, as it takes the local timezone into account instead of printing in UTC.

Now this example is very specific but since the class template `fmt::formatter` is the way to go for formatting user provided types, this scenario might occur in one form or another.

### Problem

When I develop my application `C` and use both (unrelated) libraries `A` and `B` then I believe there would be two different implementations of the same type (namely `fmt::formatter<std::chrono::system_clock::time_point>`) thus violating the ODR with undefined behaviour.

### Question

Assuming I understand the situation correctly, my two questions are:

1. Is there a way to avoid this conflict in the application `C` without altering `A` and `B` upstream?
2. If either `A` or `B` (or both) can be modified, in what ways can the conflict be resolved or fully prevented.

Comment: Terrible design! (both libs) Type traits is for describing fundamental properties of types; like can a value of type be transmogified without creating a singularity. Traits aren't for specification of user preference. You should only write traits to describe your own types.

Comment: @vitaut: The rules in play here have nothing to do with the fmt library.

Comment: @BenVoigt sure, but the question is specifically about the formatter specializations. There is even {fmt} in the title.

Comment: And it is definitely not a general question about templates.

Comment: Putting back the tag and letting the OP decide whether they want to keep it or not.

Comment: @vitaut: It most definitely is a generic question about template specializations.  And the title seems wrong, since OP doesn't say these specialization exist inside the format library, he's supposing that two other libraries break the C++ rules by adding specializations that don't belong to them.

Comment: > I am using the fmt library in my code and the canonical way user provided types can be formatted is by specializing the class template type fmt::formatter

Comment: Added a link to the relevant API to make it clear what they are referring to in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to avoid this conflict in the application C without altering A and B upstream?

You have indeed ODR violation, I don't think you can avoid conflict without altering A and/or B.

> 2. If either A or B (or both) can be modified, in what ways can the conflict be resolved or fully prevented.

Specialize only types of your own library:
so in library A, create wrapper around `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`

```
 namespace A {
     struct TimePoint {
         std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timePoint;
     };
 }


namespace fmt {
     // Specialization of formatter<TimePoint>
}
```

and then

```
auto msg = fmt::format("It is now {}", A::TimePoint{std::chrono::system_clock::now()});
```

Same for library B.